# Dead zone on touchmove event in the chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome

I noticed when I'm try to drag some item into mobile chromium, touchmove event rised after some gap from touchstart.
I wrote script to find out this gap in pixels:

`

    deadZone

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {

        var box = document.getElementById("box");
        var status = document.getElementById("status");

        var startPoint = 0;
        var moveStart = false;

        box.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            startPoint = parseInt(e.changedTouches[0].clientX);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        box.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            if(moveStart) return;
            moveStart = true;
            status.innerHTML = "deadZone: " + (e.changedTouches[0].clientX - startPoint) + "px";
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        box.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {                                                                                                                                                         
            e.preventDefault();                                                                                                                                                                                
            moveStart = false;                                                                                                                                                                                 
        });                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    });                                                                                                                                                                                                        
</script>                                                                                                                                                                                                      

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

`

And my results are: 14-30px on the right/left drag and 2-10px on up/down. It seems like box snapped to smthg in the starting of the moving it. 
How can i avoid this and start tracking touchmove from real start point?

Comment: Tested on Sony Xperia C and Sony Ericsson Live With Walkman

Comment: And in native apps such as walkman player, there is no deadzones in drag

Comment: I have replicated it here: http://jsbin.com/touchdeadzone/1/quiet - will talk to the eng team.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome for Android (M31 - the current version).  Luckily it will be fixed soon and should be in M33 or M34:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323677

The basic summary is that Android suppresses the 'slop' events so that your last chance to prevent scrolling is *always* the first touchmove.